# Sysprep.exe completely missing on both of my Windows 7 64bit machines. How should I find a workaround?

Tags: windows, sysprep, windows-pe

The `sysprep.exe` file is simply missing on my `Windows 7 64bit` machine. I tried to find it on another computer, but it wasn't found there either. I can't understand it, because on a lot of forums and even in the official articles there are a lot of references to this tool.

I've checked `system`, `system32`, `sysWOW64` folders, and even made a full search with Total Commander. I only found a `sysprep` folder in the `system32` folder, but inside was only an `en-US` subfolder, which was empty.

Then I thought I will give my `Windows PE` bootdisk a try, which I've created a while ago. No result, only the same empty `en-US` folder is present there as well.

Please if anyone knows what's happening, point me to the right direction. I need to clone my system and I'm stuck right at the first step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to extract `sysprep.exe` from the installation media.

Put the install disk into your optical drive, then select the "folder" option at Autoplay (or, if Autoplay doesn't work for you, right-click the drive and Open to view its contents)

Next, open the `sources` folder and look for the `install.wim` file.
Next, open it with the 7zip archiving program (WinRAR doesn't seem to recognize the file). 
Open any of the numbered folders (each of which represents a different version of Windows 7, but which should all contain the file you need) and navigate to `Windows\System32\sysprep` .

Then copy over the contents into your own `%windir%\System32\sysprep`.

Comment: Thanks, It was a long time ago, but this was exactly what I've done :) So I'll accept it to let this question be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though these files are missing from your original installation media. Is the original installation media from Microsoft or an OEM?

The Sysprep folder under System32 is where Sysprep is located, at the very least it should contain Sysprep.exe.

You should be able to copy the Sysprep folder from another installation so long as the Edition, Architecture, and Service Pack are the same.